# LaTeX equation is always on one page

Tags: equations

I have a very large equation of the form

```
 \begin{align}

   I(a,b) &= \int_{[a,b]} x^d\lambda (x) \\

          &= \frac{1}{10^b a!}\int_{[a,b]} x^6\lambda (x) 

\end{align}
```

The only difference is, my equation does not only have one line under the top equation but about 10. The thing is that my TeX program always wants that all these equations appear on one page. This is of course problematic, because the preceding page looks very stretched and almost empty cause I waste that much space. Therefore I want that it should be possible that this equation is written over two pages. How can I do this?

Comment: use \allowdisplaybreaks before the alignment

Comment: You *don't* have those blank lines in the actual code, have you?

Comment: no, I don't....

Answer (score 1):

How about putting the whole thing into a `figure` (one-column document) or `figure*` environment (two-column document)? I.e., you could do something like:

```
\begin{figure}%
\begin{align}
I(a,b) &= \int_{[a,b]} x^d\lambda (x) \\
       &= \frac{1}{10^b a!}\int_{[a,b]} x^6\lambda (x) 
\end{align}
\end{figure}%
```

Your equation would float, so it would not page-break but still you would not get some ugly half-empty page. Since you do not call `\caption`, the figure counter would not be affected.

(I wanted to post that as a comment, but comments cannot contain code listings.)

Comment: You may have misunderstood the OP's intent: It's *not* to keep the entire `align` material on one page, but to allow a page break.

Comment: But this would alleviate the need for a page break, while not being affected by future changes of the document in front of his equation? (As said, I wanted to do that as mere comment first, anyway)

Comment: As I see it, it's the *lack of a suitable page break* that's the problem. Putting the material inside a float will likely create a whole new set of problems, right? Issuing the instruction `\allowdisplaybreaks`, as suggested in a comment by David Carlisle, solved the OP's problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right, Prof. Carlisle's answer is the right one. Using `figure`, however, has some advantages in shorter documents, say research papers. The equation will be laid out somewhere nearby as a whole, without disturbing the flow of the paper. Still, I should probably not have added this idea.