# Positioning and spacing of matrices

Tags: positioning, matrices

I have the following matrix as part of the text.

```
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

$
B = \begin{bmatrix*}[r]

-35833 & -31743 & -25098 & -15178 & 0 & 26332 & 83775 & 278053\\
139167 & 115894 & 84478 & 42736 & -14684 & -102432 & -261195 & -625923\\
-311667 & -245610 & -168059 & -75042 & 41775 & 203744 & 463854 & 964174\\
479167 & 354802 & 226562 & 87117 & -73865 & -279459 & -581824 & -1104074\\
-551667 & -379883 & -225687 & -74437 & 86118 & 276252 & 536428 & 953089\\
479167 & 298423 & 161307 & 41879 & -73865 & -200977 & -364008 & -610219\\
-311667 & -166016 & -79330 & -14573 & 41775 & 98840 & 167683 & 266968\\
139167 & 51824 & 19223 & -96 & -14684 & -28125 & -43379 & -64691
\end{bmatrix*}
$

%omitted text

\end{document}
```

When I view my document, it looks like this

[image]

The matrix stretches too far out right. How do I ensure that it is more centered with respect to the text below?

Comment: Maybe you could try with another size font for that matrix.

Comment: @juanuni How do I do that?

Comment: I suggest you read all responses and comments in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60453/reducing-font-size-in-equation and choice the one you like.

Comment: I was a little unsure with most of the options I'd seen earlier since they involved having to use something like psmallmatrix which leads to the loss of right alignment.

Comment: I was confused because you have a large array as part of a mathematical text inline. Maybe is advisable put your large matrix within `\[` `\]`

Comment: @Aditya, you have tri options to copy with your problem: (i) use smaller fornt, for example `scriptsize˙` (which will make your matrix difficult to read), (ii) split matrix into two part (see my unswer in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257313/shrinking-or-splitting-some-equations-in-a-group-of-equations) or (iii) locally enlarge text width (that matrix will extent out of text, similarly as you have now, but in controlled manner).

Comment: @Zarko, I used the `\begingroup\makeatletter\def\f@size{8}\check@mathfonts` command from the thread that juanuni had suggested and it worked fine.

Answer (score 6):

You can play with the value of `\arraycolsep`, or use the `medmath` command, from `nccmath`, which sets the fontsize to `~ 80%` of \displaystyle. You also can combine both solutions:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\[ \setlength{\arraycolsep}{4pt}
  B = \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
  -35833 & -31743 & -25098 & -15178 & 0 & 26332 & 83775 & 278053\\
  139167 & 115894 & 84478 & 42736 & -14684 & -102432 & -261195 & -625923\\
  -311667 & -245610 & -168059 & -75042 & 41775 & 203744 & 463854 & 964174\\
  479167 & 354802 & 226562 & 87117 & -73865 & -279459 & -581824 & -1104074\\
  -551667 & -379883 & -225687 & -74437 & 86118 & 276252 & 536428 & 953089\\
  479167 & 298423 & 161307 & 41879 & -73865 & -200977 & -364008 & -610219\\
  -311667 & -166016 & -79330 & -14573 & 41775 & 98840 & 167683 & 266968\\
  139167 & 51824 & 19223 & -96 & -14684 & -28125 & -43379 & -64691
  \end{bmatrix*}
\]
\vskip1cm
\[
  B = \medmath{\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
    -35833 & -31743 & -25098 & -15178 & 0 & 26332 & 83775 & 278053\\
    139167 & 115894 & 84478 & 42736 & -14684 & -102432 & -261195 & -625923\\
    -311667 & -245610 & -168059 & -75042 & 41775 & 203744 & 463854 & 964174\\
    479167 & 354802 & 226562 & 87117 & -73865 & -279459 & -581824 & -1104074\\
    -551667 & -379883 & -225687 & -74437 & 86118 & 276252 & 536428 & 953089\\
    479167 & 298423 & 161307 & 41879 & -73865 & -200977 & -364008 & -610219\\
    -311667 & -166016 & -79330 & -14573 & 41775 & 98840 & 167683 & 266968\\
    139167 & 51824 & 19223 & -96 & -14684 & -28125 & -43379 & -64691
    \end{bmatrix*}}
\]

\vskip1cm
\[ \setlength{\arraycolsep}{3pt}
  B = \medmath{\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
    -35833 & -31743 & -25098 & -15178 & 0 & 26332 & 83775 & 278053\\
    139167 & 115894 & 84478 & 42736 & -14684 & -102432 & -261195 & -625923\\
    -311667 & -245610 & -168059 & -75042 & 41775 & 203744 & 463854 & 964174\\
    479167 & 354802 & 226562 & 87117 & -73865 & -279459 & -581824 & -1104074\\
    -551667 & -379883 & -225687 & -74437 & 86118 & 276252 & 536428 & 953089\\
    479167 & 298423 & 161307 & 41879 & -73865 & -200977 & -364008 & -610219\\
    -311667 & -166016 & -79330 & -14573 & 41775 & 98840 & 167683 & 266968\\
    139167 & 51824 & 19223 & -96 & -14684 & -28125 & -43379 & -64691
    \end{bmatrix*}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Both options are still a little too large. I tried working with lower arguments to `\arraycolsep` but the matrix becomes too clustered then. I got a solution as mentioned above.

Comment: How about a combination of both solutions? Please see my updated answer.