# Confusion matrix in LaTeX

Tags: tables, matrices, plot, comments, pattern

I used the proposed example in the "[confusion matrix using only LaTeX code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271465/confusion-matrix-using-only-latex-code?newreg=d515c2aae35543e78446faf5cc19b5a9)"

I increased the number of classes and until 9x9 confusion matrix, everything worked very well, but for 10 or higher numbers it got some errors. I upload the example with 10 columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\MyBox[1]{%
  \fbox{\parbox[c][.7cm][c]{.7cm}{\centering #1}}%
}
\newcommand\MyVBox[1]{%
  \parbox[c][.7cm][c]{1cm}{\centering\bfseries #1}%
}  
\newcommand\MyHBox[2][\dimexpr.7cm+2\fboxsep\relax]{%
  \parbox[c][1cm][c]{#1}{\centering\bfseries #2}%
}  
\newcommand\MyTBox[10]{%
  \MyVBox{#1}\MyBox{#2}\hspace*{-\fboxrule}\MyBox{#3}\hspace*{-\fboxrule}%
  \MyBox{#4}\hspace*{-\fboxrule}%
  \MyBox{#5}\hspace*{-\fboxrule}%
  \MyBox{#6}\hspace*{-\fboxrule}%
  \MyBox{#7}\hspace*{-\fboxrule}%
  \MyBox{#8}\hspace*{-\fboxrule}%
  \MyBox{#9}\hspace*{-\fboxrule}%
  \MyBox{#10}\par\vspace{-\fboxrule}
}  

\begin{document}

{
\offinterlineskip
\raisebox{-5cm}[0pt][0pt]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[c][0pt][c]{1cm}{\textbf{Source2}\\[20pt]}}}\par
\hspace*{1cm}\MyHBox[\dimexpr5.1cm+6\fboxsep\relax]{Source1}\par
\hspace*{1cm}\MyHBox{A}\MyHBox{B}\MyHBox{C}
\MyHBox{D}\MyHBox{E}\MyHBox{F}\par

\MyTBox{A}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}
\MyTBox{B}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}{10}
\MyTBox{C}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}{10}{11}
\MyTBox{D}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}{10}{11}{12}
\MyTBox{E}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}{10}{11}{12}{13}
\MyTBox{F}{6}{7}{8}{9}{10}{11}{12}{13}{14}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) latex macros only support up to 9 args. Perhaps you should start by explaining what exactly you are trying to do (which is not really obvious from your code).

Comment: try add `\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{12} `, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280520/rotate-matrix-in-latex/280542#280542.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than using 10 arguments for your macro you're better off using a comma separated list and then processing it using something like `docsvlist` from the `etoolbox` package. With this small modification your code produces:

[image]

Here's the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\MyBox[1]{%
  \fbox{\parbox[c][.7cm][c]{.7cm}{\centering #1}}%
}
\newcommand\MyVBox[1]{%
  \parbox[c][.7cm][c]{1cm}{\centering\bfseries #1}%
}
\newcommand\MyHBox[2][\dimexpr.7cm+2\fboxsep\relax]{%
  \parbox[c][1cm][c]{#1}{\centering\bfseries #2}%
}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand\MyTBox[3]{%
  \MyVBox{#1}
  \renewcommand*\do[1]{\MyBox{##1}\hspace*{-\fboxrule}}
  \docsvlist{#2}
  \MyBox{#3}\par\vspace{-\fboxrule}
}

\begin{document}

{
\offinterlineskip
\raisebox{-5cm}[0pt][0pt]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[c][0pt][c]{1cm}{\textbf{Source2}\\[20pt]}}}\par
\hspace*{1cm}\MyHBox[\dimexpr5.1cm+6\fboxsep\relax]{Source1}\par
\hspace*{1cm}\MyHBox{A}\MyHBox{B}\MyHBox{C}
\MyHBox{D}\MyHBox{E}\MyHBox{F}\par

\MyTBox{A}{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}{9}
\MyTBox{B}{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}{10}
\MyTBox{C}{3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}{11}
\MyTBox{D}{4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}{12}
\MyTBox{E}{5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}{13}
\MyTBox{F}{6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13}{14}
}

\end{document}
```

I made `\MyTBox` have three arguments as there is "special" processing for the header, body and footer respectively. This said, I'd probably do this differently using something like `tikz`, although this really depends on what you are really putting inside these macros:) -- but I like your macros too!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I followed the comment from @daleif and managed to do it.

```
\newcommand\MyTBox[9]{%
 %....
 \MyTBoxcontinued
 }  
\newcommand\MyTBoxcontinued[2]{%
 %two more arguments
 }
```

In the following, I uploaded the code and the resulted image.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newcommand\MyBox[1]{%
  \fbox{\parbox[c][.7cm][c]{.7cm}{\centering #1}}%
}
\newcommand\MyVBox[1]{%
  \parbox[c][.7cm][c]{1cm}{\centering\bfseries #1}%
}  
\newcommand\MyHBox[2][\dimexpr.7cm+2\fboxsep\relax]{%
  \parbox[c][1cm][c]{#1}{\centering\bfseries #2}%
}  
\newcommand\MyTBox[9]{%
  \MyVBox{#1}\MyBox{#2}\hspace*{-\fboxrule}\MyBox{#3}\hspace*{-\fboxrule}%
  \MyBox{#4}\hspace*{-\fboxrule}%
  \MyBox{#5}\hspace*{-\fboxrule}%
  \MyBox{#6}\hspace*{-\fboxrule}%
  \MyBox{#7}\hspace*{-\fboxrule}%
  \MyBox{#8}\hspace*{-\fboxrule}%
  \MyBox{#9}\hspace*{-\fboxrule}%
  \MyTBoxcontinued
}  
\newcommand\MyTBoxcontinued[2]{%
 \MyBox{#1}\hspace*{-\fboxrule}%    
 \MyBox{#2}\par\vspace{-\fboxrule}
}

\begin{document}

{
\offinterlineskip
\hspace*{1cm}\MyHBox{/\textipa{a}/}\MyHBox{/\textipa{E}/}\MyHBox{\textipa{/I/}}
\MyHBox{/\reflectbox{\textipa{c}}/}\MyHBox{/\textipa{U}/}\MyHBox{/\textipa{a:}/}
\MyHBox{/\textipa{e}/}\MyHBox{/\textipa{i}/}\MyHBox{/\textipa{o}/}\MyHBox{/\textipa{u}/}\par

\MyTBox{/\textipa{a}/}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}{10}
\MyTBox{/\textipa{E}/}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}{10}{11}
\MyTBox{/\textipa{I}/}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}{10}{11}{12}
\MyTBox{/\reflectbox{\textipa{c}}/}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}{10}{11}{12}{13}
\MyTBox{/\textipa{U}/}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}{10}{11}{12}{13}{14}
\MyTBox{/\textipa{a:}/}{6}{7}{8}{9}{10}{11}{12}{13}{14}{15}
\MyTBox{/\textipa{e}/}{7}{8}{9}{10}{11}{12}{13}{14}{15}{16}
\MyTBox{/\textipa{o}/}{8}{9}{10}{11}{12}{13}{14}{15}{16}{17}
\MyTBox{/\textipa{u}/}{9}{10}{11}{12}{13}{14}{15}{16}{17}{18}
}

\end{document}
```