# Matrix is not completely fitted in the PDF generated from LaTex

Tags: math-mode, wolfram-mathematica

I have the following LaTex code for a 10x10 matrix (which I have imported from Mathematica),

```
"$$\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
 -2 (\text{$\beta $111} +\text{$\beta $224} x^2 & 0
   & 2 \text{$\alpha $111} & 2 \text{$\alpha $223} y^2 & 2 \text{$\alpha $224} x^2 &
   0 & 0 & 0 & x y (\text{$\alpha $223}+\text{$\alpha $224}) & x y (\text{$\alpha
   $223}+\text{$\alpha $224}) \\
   +\text{$\beta $223} y^2)&&&&&&&&& \\
 0 & -2 (\text{$\beta $222}+\text{$\beta $115} x^2
   & 0 & 2 \text{$\alpha $115} x^2 & 2 \text{$\alpha $116} y^2 & 2 \text{$\alpha
   $222} & 0 & 0 & -x y (\text{$\alpha $115}+\text{$\alpha $116}) & -x y
   (\text{$\alpha $115}+\text{$\alpha $116}) \\
   &+\text{$\beta $116} y^2)&&&&&&&& \\
 2 \text{$\beta $111} & 0 & -2 (\text{$\alpha $111}+\text{$\beta $222}) & 0 & 0 & 0 &
   2 \text{$\alpha $222} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 2 \text{$\beta $223} y^2 & 2 \text{$\beta $115} x^2 & 0 & -2 (\text{$\alpha
   $115} x^2+\text{$\beta $229} x^2 & 0 & 0 & 2 \text{$\alpha $117} y^2 & 2 \text{$\alpha $229} x^2 & -x y
   (-\text{$\alpha $116}+\text{$\alpha $224}
   & -x y (-\text{$\alpha $116}+\text{$\alpha $224} \\
    &&&+\text{$\alpha $223} y^2+\text{$\beta $117}
   y^2)&&&&&+\text{$\beta $118}-\text{$\beta $2210})&+\text{$\beta $118}-\text{$\beta
   $2210})
   \\
 2 \text{$\beta $224} x^2 & 2 \text{$\beta $116} y^2 & 0 & 0 & -2 (\text{$\alpha
   $224} x^2+\text{$\beta $118} x^2 & 0 & 2 \text{$\alpha $118} x^2 & 2 \text{$\alpha $2210} y^2 & -x y
   (-\text{$\alpha $115}+\text{$\alpha $223} &
   -x y (-\text{$\alpha $115}+\text{$\alpha $223} \\
    &&&&+\text{$\alpha $116} y^2+\text{$\beta $2210}
   y^2)&&&&+\text{$\beta $117}-\text{$\beta $229})&+\text{$\beta $117}-\text{$\beta
   $229})
   \\
 0 & 2 \text{$\beta $222} & 0 & 0 & 0 & -2 (\text{$\alpha $222}+\text{$\beta $111}) &
   0 & 2 \text{$\alpha $111} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 2 \text{$\beta $222} & 2 \text{$\beta $117} y^2 & 2 \text{$\beta $118} x^2 &
   0 & -2 (\text{$\alpha $222}+\text{$\alpha $117} x^2 & 0 & x y (\text{$\beta $117}+\text{$\beta $118}) & x y (\text{$\beta
   $117}+\text{$\beta $118}) \\
   &&&&&&+\text{$\alpha $118}
   y^2)&&&\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \text{$\beta $229} x^2 & 2 \text{$\beta $2210} y^2 & 2 \text{$\beta
   $111} & 0 & -2 (\text{$\alpha $111}+\text{$\alpha $2210} x^2& -x y (\text{$\beta $2210}+\text{$\beta $229}) & -x y
   (\text{$\beta $2210}+\text{$\beta $229})\\
   &&&&&&&+\text{$\alpha
   $229} y^2) && \\
 x y (\text{$\beta $223}+\text{$\beta $224}) & -x y (\text{$\beta $115}+\text{$\beta
   $116}) & 0 & x y (\text{$\alpha $118}-\text{$\alpha $2210} & x y (\text{$\alpha $117}-\text{$\alpha
   $229} & 0 & x y (\text{$\alpha
   $117}+\text{$\alpha $118}) & -x y (\text{$\alpha $2210}+\text{$\alpha $229}) & -i
   (\text{l1}-\text{l2}) & 0 \\
   &&&-\text{$\beta
   $116}+\text{$\beta $224})&-\text{$\beta $115}+\text{$\beta $223})&&&&-\text{$\alpha $115} x^2-\text{$\alpha $224} x^2&
   \\
   &&&&&&&&-\text{$\beta
   $118} x^2-\text{$\beta $229} x^2&
   \\
   &&&&&&&&-\text{$\alpha $116} y^2-\text{$\alpha $223}
   y^2&
   \\
   &&&&&&&&-\text{$\beta $117} y^2-\text{$\beta $2210} y^2&
   \\
 x y (\text{$\beta $223}+\text{$\beta $224}) & -x y (\text{$\beta $115}+\text{$\beta
   $116}) & 0 & x y (\text{$\alpha $118}-\text{$\alpha $2210} & x y (\text{$\alpha $117}-\text{$\alpha
   $229} & 0 & x y (\text{$\alpha
   $117}+\text{$\alpha $118}) & -x y (\text{$\alpha $2210}+\text{$\alpha $229}) & 0 &
   -i (\text{l2}-\text{l1})
   \\
   &&&-\text{$\beta
   $116}+\text{$\beta $224})&-\text{$\beta $115}+\text{$\beta $223})&&&&&-\text{$\alpha $115} x^2-\text{$\alpha $224}x^2
   \\
   &&&&&&&&&-\text{$\beta
   $118} x^2-\text{$\beta $229} x^2
   \\
   &&&&&&&&&-\text{$\alpha $116} y^2-\text{$\alpha $223}
   y^2
   \\
     &&&&&&&&&-\text{$\beta $117} y^2-\text{$\beta $2210} y^2 \\
\end{bmatrix*} $$
\end{document}
```

complete matrix is fitted in the PDF for the following latex format,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amsthm}
\usepackage{array}
```

have also attached the complete matrix in this format.

[image]

But for the format ,

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{geometry,mathtools}
\usepackage{comment}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1.5cm]{geometry}"
```

I was getting up to column six for the following document type,

So, is there any way to fit the complete matrix in this format?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a minimal working example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: why on earch is mathematica using `\text{$...$}` on each value?

Comment: There is no way that is ever going to fit on a single page. I managed to get it to fit in landscape if I scaled it down to approx 1.7pt font size. In comparison the latex detail is 10pt, so the end result is not readable.

Comment: The number after \alpha and \beta are subscripts? If so you can gain some space.

Comment: We need to know the layout of your page. SO please provide complete small document (MWE) .

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I have reduced my matrix size by using few trick but still its not fitted in the PDF completely.

Comment: You should provide MWE (Minimal Working Example, small complete/compilable document, which reproduce your problem), not only code fragments. Showed image of your matrix is not produced with your code (it is erroneous). Let me repeat @daleif comment: your matrix, as is written, can not be fit on one page. See, if (my answer) on the question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257313/shrinking-or-splitting-some-equations-in-a-group-of-equations can help you, i.e. is acceptable to you.

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix is realy huge and as it is writen, can not be fit on one page. Possible solution can be is splitting it onto two parts:

[image]

This solution is based on assumption that number at `\alpha` and `\beta` are their indices. If this is case, please let us know.

After removing all clutter from your code, the MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{multline}
\medmath{
\widehat{\widetilde{\mathcal{M}}} =
   \left[\begin{array}{*{5}{c}}
\begin{multlined}[t]-2 \bigl(\beta_{111}+\\[-2.4ex]
\beta_{224} x^2+\beta_{223} y^2\bigr)\end{multlined}
    & 0
        & 2 \alpha_{111}
            & 2 \alpha_{223} y^2
                & 2 \alpha_{224} x^2    \\%%%%
0
    & \begin{multlined}[t]-2 \bigl(\beta_{222}+\\[-2.4ex]
    \beta_{115} x^2+\beta_{116} y^2\bigr)\end{multlined}
        & 0
            & 2 \alpha_{115} x^2
                & 2 \alpha_{116} y^2    \\%%%%
 \beta_{111}
    & 0
        & -2 \bigl(\alpha_{111}+\beta_{222}\bigr)
            & 0
                & 0    \\%%%%
2 \beta_{223} y^2
    & 2 \beta_{115} x^2
        & 0
            & \begin{multlined}[t]-2 \bigl(\alpha_{115} x^2+ \beta_{229} x^2+ \\[-2.4ex]
            \alpha_{223} y^2 + \beta_{117} y^2\bigr)\end{multlined}
                & 0    \\%%%%
2 \beta_{224} x^2
    & 2 \beta_{116} y^2
        & 0
            & 0
                & \begin{multlined}[t]-2 \bigl(\alpha_{224} x^2+\beta_{118} x^2 +\\[-2.4ex]
                \alpha_{116} y^2 +\beta_{2210}y^2\bigr)\end{multlined}    \\%%%%
0
    & 2 \beta_{222}
        & 0
            & 0
                & 0    \\%%%%
0
    & 0
        & 2 \beta_{222}
            & 2 \beta_{117} y^2
                & 2 \beta_{118} x^2    \\%%%%
0
    & 0
        & 0
            & 2 \beta_{229} x^2
                & 2 \beta_{2210} y^2    \\%%%%
x y \bigl(\beta_{223}+\beta_{224}\bigr)
    & -x y (\beta_{115}+\beta_{116}\bigr)
        & 0
            & \begin{multlined}[t]x y \bigl(\alpha_{118}-\alpha_{2210}-\\[-2.4ex]
            \beta_{116}+\beta_{224}\bigr)\end{multlined}
                & \begin{multlined}[t]x y \bigl(\alpha_{117}-\alpha_{229}-\\[-2.4ex]
                \beta_{115}+\beta_{223}\bigr)\end{multlined}    \\%%%%
x y \bigl(\beta_{223}+\beta_{224}\bigr)
    & -x y \bigl(\beta_{115}+\beta_{116}\bigr)
        & 0
            & \begin{multlined}[t]v y \bigl(\alpha_{118}-\alpha_{2210}-\\[-2.4ex]
            \beta_{116}+\beta_{224}\bigr)\end{multlined}
                & \begin{multlined}[t]x y\bigl(\alpha_{117}-\alpha_{229}-\\[-1ex]
                \beta_{115}+\beta_{223}\bigr)\end{multlined}
    \end{array}\right.}   \\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% SECOND PART
    \medmath{
    \left.\begin{array}{*{5}{c}}
0
    & 0
        & 0
            & x y \bigl(\alpha_{223}+\alpha_{224}\bigr)
                & x y \bigl(\alpha_{223}+\alpha_{224}\bigr) \\
2 \alpha_{222}
    & 0
        & 0
            & -x y \bigl(\alpha_{115}+\alpha_{116}\bigr)
                & -x y \bigl(\alpha_{115}+\alpha_{116}\bigr) \\
0
    & 2 \alpha_{222}
        & 0
            & 0
                & 0 \\
0
    & 2 \alpha_{117} y^2
        & 2 \alpha_{229} x^2
            & \begin{multlined}[t]
            -x y \bigl(-\alpha_{116}+\alpha_{224}+\\[-2.4ex]
            \beta_{118}-\beta_{2210}\bigr)\end{multlined}
                & \begin{multlined}[t]-x\bigl(-\alpha_{116}+\alpha_{224}+\\[-2.4ex]
                \beta_{118}-\beta_{2210}\bigr)\end{multlined} \\                
0
    & \begin{multlined}[t]
    -2 \bigl(\alpha_{222}+\\[-2.4ex]
    \alpha_{117} x^2+\alpha_{118} y^2\bigr)\end{multlined}
        & 0
            & x y (\beta_{117}+\beta_{118}\bigr)
                & x y \bigl(\beta_{117}+\beta_{118}\bigr) \\
0
    & 2 \alpha_{118} x^2
        & 2 \alpha_{2210} y^2
            & \begin{multlined}[t]
            -x y\bigl(-\alpha_{115}+\alpha_{223}+\\[-2.4ex]
            \beta_{117}-\beta_{229}\bigr)\end{multlined}
                & \begin{multlined}[t]
                -x y \bigl(-\alpha_{115}+\alpha_{223}+\\[-2.4ex] \beta_{117}-\beta_{229}\bigr)\end{multlined} \\
-2 \bigl(\alpha_{222}+\beta_{111}\bigr)
    & 0
        & 2 \alpha_{111}
            & 0
                & 0 \\
0
    & \begin{multlined}[t]-2 \bigl(\alpha_{222}+\\[-2.4ex]
    \alpha_{117} x^2+\alpha_{118} y^2\bigr)\end{multlined}
        & 0
            & x y (\beta_{117}+\beta_{118}\bigr)
                & x y \bigl(\beta_{117}+\beta_{118}\bigr) \\
2 \beta_{111}
    & 0
        & \begin{multlined}[t]-2 \bigl(\alpha_{111}+\\[-2.4ex]
        \alpha_{2210} x^2 +\alpha_{229} y^2\bigr)\end{multlined}
            & -x y \bigl(\beta_{2210}+\beta_{229}\bigr)
                & -x y\bigl(\beta_{2210}+\beta_{229}\bigr) \\
0
    & x y \bigl(\alpha_{117}+\alpha_{118}\bigr)
        & -x y \bigl(\alpha_{2210}+\alpha_{229}\bigr)
            & \begin{multlined}[t]
            -i (l1-l2)-\alpha_{115} x^2-\\[-2.4ex]
            \alpha_{224} x^2-\beta_{118} x^2-\\
            \beta_{229}x^2-\alpha_{116} y^2-\\ 
            \alpha_{223}y^2-\beta_{117} y^2-\\
            \beta_{2210} y^2\end{multlined}
                & 0     \\
0
    & x y \bigl(\alpha_{117}+\alpha_{118}\bigr)
        & -x y \bigl(\alpha_{2210}+\alpha_{229}\bigr)
            & 0
                & \begin{multlined}[t]-i(l2-l1)-\alpha_{115}x^2-\\[-2.4ex]
                \alpha_{224}x^2-\beta_{118} x^2-\\
                \beta_{229} x^2-\alpha_{116}y^2-\\
                \alpha_{223} y^2-\beta_{117} y^2-\\
                \beta_{2210} y^2\end{multlined}
    \end{array}\right]}
\end{multline}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```