# Long matrix equation splitting

Tags: equations, matrices, split

I am trying to write a long equation which includes a long matrix. I have tried many solutions (multiline, split) from the other so answers but the problem still exists. Could you help me to find out the problem? Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{multiline}
\label{nineth}
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x}\\
\dot{y}\\
\dot{z}\\
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
R_{0}^{0} \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 0\\ 1 
\end{bmatrix} x
(d^{0}_{5}-d^{0}_{0}) & 
R^{0}_{1} \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 0\\ 1 
\end{bmatrix} x
(d^{0}_{5}-d^{0}_{1}) & 
R^{0}_{2} \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 0\\ 1 
\end{bmatrix} x
(d^{0}_{5}-d^{0}_{2}) & 
R^{0}_{3} \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 0\\ 1 
\end{bmatrix} x
(d^{0}_{5}-d^{0}_{3}) & \\
R^{0}_{4} \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 0\\ 1  
\end{bmatrix} x
(d^{0}_{5}-d^{0}_{4}) &
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{\theta_{1}} \\
\dot{\theta_{2}} \\
\dot{\theta_{3}} \\
\dot{\theta_{4}} \\
\dot{\theta_{5}} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{multiline}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

As you can see there are 3 terms in the equation, 2nd term should be splitted but the result of the code is wrong in the image. [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! `multiline` does not exist and should be `multline`, which cannot be nested in an `equation`. But apart from this I really do not understand how the equation is supposed to look like.

Comment: The secondterm in the image is a one matrix R_{0}_{4} ... should be on the same row as well others element of the matrix or the 3rd term should be near to the R_{0}_{4} element of the 2nd term. `multline` did not give any result btw.

Comment: Exactly it is 1x5 row vector. Yes everyting what you explained, (-) is also supposed to be (=).

Comment: If I understand your setup  correctly, the big matrix is supposed to be a 3x5 matrix; is this correct? (The `x` characters denote multiplication, right?) If my assumption is correct, why not just state that `\dot{x}=0`, `\dot{y}=0`, and provide an inline math expression for `\dot{z}`?

Comment: Yes it is for cross product. The matrix is as you said 3x5.

Comment: See my answer on question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257313/

Comment: Thanks. Please also clarify whether the terms `R^0_{...}` and `d^0_{...}` are scalars, vectors, or matrices.

Comment: @Zarko thank you so much. I was able to write like you. I wish I could vote up.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that the matrix form is really helpful for your readers; in this case a summation seems much better:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix} \dot{x} \\ \dot{y} \\ \dot{z} \end{bmatrix} -
\sum_{k=0}^4 R^{0}_{k}
             \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
             x(d^{0}_{5}-d^{0}_{k}) \dot{\theta}_{k+1}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix} \dot{x} \\ \dot{y} \\ \dot{z} \end{bmatrix} -
\begin{bmatrix} S_0 & S_1 & S_2 & S_3 & S_4 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \dot{\theta}_1 \\ \dot{\theta}_2 \\ \dot{\theta}_3 \\ \dot{\theta}_4 \\ \dot{\theta}_5
\end{bmatrix},
\qquad S_k=R^{0}_{k}\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}x(d^{0}_{5}-d^{0}_{k})
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I propose to use `multlined` environment (from `mathtools`) *inside*  the large matrix, and the `geometry` package to have more decent margins by default.

*Unrelated*: needless to  load `inputenc` with option `[utf8]`  nowadays (unless you have an old version of LaTeX), nor `amsfonts` if you load `amssymb` – the latter does it for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\setlength{\bigstrutjot}{1ex}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{nineth}
 \begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x}\bigstrut[t]\\
\dot{y}\\
\dot{z}\bigstrut[b]
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{multlined}
R_{0}^{0} \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 0\\ 1
\end{bmatrix} x
(d^{0}_{5}-d^{0}_{0}) \quad
R^{0}_{1} \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 0\\ 1
\end{bmatrix} x
(d^{0}_{5}-d^{0}_{1})\quad
R^{0}_{2} \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 0\\ 1
\end{bmatrix} x
(d^{0}_{5}-d^{0}_{2})\\[-2ex]
R^{0}_{3} \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 0\\ 1
\end{bmatrix} x
(d^{0}_{5}-d^{0}_{3}) \quad
R^{0}_{4} \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 0\\ 1
\end{bmatrix} x
(d^{0}_{5}-d^{0}_{4})
\end{multlined}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{\theta_{1}}\bigstrut[t] \\[0.5ex]
\dot{\theta_{2}} \\[0.5ex]
\dot{\theta_{3}} \\[0.5ex]
\dot{\theta_{4}} \\[0.5ex]
\dot{\theta_{5}}\bigstrut[b]
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much but it is not like I wanted. I have found the answer here [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257313/shrinking-or-splitting-some-equations-in-a-group-of-equations)

Comment: I only wanted to show that `multline` can be nested if you load `mathtools` and use `multlined` in the right place. This being said, I don't understand what you wanted.